# Is it the realm file deleted when uninstalling iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I don't have an iOS device right now so I've tried with the simulator (there the file is not deleted) but I want to confirm if the result is the same. Is it the realm database deleted when the user uninstall the app?

EDIT: How I initialize Realm before any transaction: `RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];`

Comment: Can you share a code how you initialise realm?

Comment: @ilya Yeah done

Comment: @JaimeAlcántaraArnela yes if you delete and uninstall the Application all the database deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you leave the Realm file in the Documents directory, then if the user performs an iCloud or iTunes backup, the file will be backed up. All this means though is that if the user decides to upgrade to a new device and perform a restore using the old device's backup image, the Realm file will be restored then. If the user deletes the app from your old device before then, the iCloud backup will also be deleted and Realm file too.

Comment: Is this file placed into the documents directory by default?

Comment: Yes by default file are placed in document directory